# Upgrade to 3.1 - Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_cache_get()

Tags: upgrade, fatal-error

I just upgraded to 3.1, and after refreshing I get the following error:

> **Fatal error**: Call to undefined
>   function wp_cache_get() in
>   **/public_html/blog/wp-includes/functions.php**
>   on line **336**

A quick google search led me to [this post](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/upgrade-to-31-wp_cache_get-issue) on WordPress support forum, however I tried disabling all plugins as suggested, and I'm using TwentyTen as my only theme.

I also set `define('WP_CACHE', false)` in the config, didn't help...

Any ideas before I attempt to roll everything back?

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd guess a plugin at fault, disable all your plugins and see if you're able to run the upgrade as Marja pointed out, **wp-admin/upgrade.php** (they don't need to be disabled permanently, just long enough to get your site working again).

Comment: @t31os: I tried, unfortunately I got the error on every page. I ended up reverting to 3.0.5 (from backup)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was linked to the [WP-Hive plugin](http://wp-hive.com/), and it was (partially) resolved, when the plugin's author had [fixed the problem](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/upgrade-to-31-wp_cache_get-issue#post-1974988).

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a `object-cache.php` in your wp-content directory? If so, rename it.
But first make sure the upgrade replaced all new files. Upgrade per FTP and watch out for failed transfers.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems upgrading too. Not the same as you though. I got a complete blank screen after entering my login details.My sites worked fine at the frontend though.
The plugin option didn´t work for me either.
What I did was ran(It´s a local setup):
http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/upgrade.php

I could then get in to my admin again,
Finnish the database update
and run the 3.1 upgrade
Basically I just followed the messages at the top of my screen again 
and now I´m all fine!

Hope it helps!

Comment: I wish... I can't even get to the admin page!